# mdframed: unable to reproduce the example environment with figures

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, mdframed

I used `mdframed` but I am unable to reproduce the `example` environment (?) from [this primer](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/crs/vignettes/spline_primer.pdf). The main problem is with figures (graphics, plots), of course. Any help?

[image]

Comment: Can you show an attempt?

Comment: @Papiro don't use floats; use `center` or a `minipage` and `\captionof` from the [`capt-of`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/capt-of) package if your plots/images/tables require captions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`mdframed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) does not allow floats within the `mdframed` environment<sup>*</sup>. The reason for this is obvious, since the float should be allowed to move around in the document, and fixing it within a block-like environment prohibits this movement. In fact, [LaTeX will complain with an error](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-fllost)

```
! LaTeX Error: Float(s) lost.
```

Instead, create a "fake" float by using (say) the `center` environment with a caption created by `\captionof{<fenv>}[<ToC entry>]{<caption>}` (provided by the [`capt-of`](http://ctan.org/pkg/capt-of) and [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) packages). As an extra step to group the image and its caption, perhaps wrap them inside a `minipage`.

<sub><sup>*</sup> This might change in the future, based on [Marco's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116881/color-pages-in-specific-sections-in-lyx/116891#comment259329_116891).</sub>